# How to exclude or replace app dependencies in androidTest configuration

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I have an application where the `androidTest` configuration has hit the infamous [dex 64k method limit](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) with both application and test library dependencies contributing to the method count.

To get the method count below 64k again, I want to stub out some of the dependencies. For the actual application, I have replaced

```
app
+-- largeDependency
```

with a flavored wrapper library:

```
app
+-- dependencyWrapper
    +-- largeDependency
```

For test configuration I want to replace the `dependencyWrapper` with a stub flavor that does not bring in `largeDependency`:

```
androidTest
+-- app
    +-- dependencyWrapperStub
```

How can I override the build flavor in the test configuration? The naive approach

```
compile project(path: 'dependencyWrapper', configuration: 'prod')
androidTestCompile project(path: 'dependencyWrapper', configuration: 'stub')
```

does not work as the test configuration depends on the `app` configuration that brings in its dependencies and now there are two copies of the wrapper library.

Comment: There might be a way to use an `exclude` closure to achieve this (have `androidTestCompile` exclude the `compile` dependency), though I haven't tried that in this sort of scenario.

Comment: The dependency from tests to application is implicit so I don't see there's an obvious place to put the `exclude` filtering in. It's not the explicit `androidTestCompile` that brings in the unwanted dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to refactor the dependencies:

```
app
+-- appLibrary
|   +-- dependencyWrapperInterface
+-- dependencyWrapperImpl
    +-- dependencyWrapperInterface
    +-- largeDependency
```

The old application is now a library project `appLibrary` that links against `dependencyWrapperInterface` module. It is really just an interface with an empty stub implementation. The thin `app` project now includes `dependencyWrapperImpl` module that implements the same interface and brings in the `largeDependency` to do so. `app` injects the `dependencyWrapperImpl` interface implementation to `appLibrary`.

Tests are run on the `appLibrary` with reduced dependency set that are now below 64k again:

```
androidTest
+-- appLibrary
    +-- dependencyWrapperInterface
```

Comment: This solved the original problem but other approaches welcome, too.